# how to call StoredProcedure or Functions from a MySQL Trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, triggers

I am working on MySQL 5.1.3 and using PHPMyAdmin 3.1.3.1 to access it. With PHP as the Server side scripting Language. My problem statement is can we call a Stored Procedure or Function from the Trigger statement so that when ever an INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE trigger is called, it calls the SP for updating some other tables according to the logic defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look here [Mysql Trigger Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/trigger-syntax.html)

```
mysql> delimiter //  
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON account  
    -> FOR EACH ROW  
    -> BEGIN  
    ->     IF NEW.amount < 0 THEN  
    ->         SET NEW.amount = 0;  
    ->     ELSEIF NEW.amount > 100 THEN  
    ->         SET NEW.amount = 100;  
    ->     END IF;  
    -> END;//  
mysql> delimiter;
```

It can be easier to define a stored procedure separately and then invoke it from the trigger using a simple `CALL` statement. This is also advantageous if you want to invoke the same routine from within several triggers.

There are some limitations on what can appear in statements that a trigger executes when activated:

The trigger cannot use the `CALL` statement to invoke stored procedures that return data to the client or that use dynamic SQL. (Stored procedures are permitted to return data to the trigger through `OUT` or `INOUT` parameters.)

The trigger cannot use statements that explicitly or implicitly begin or end a transaction such as `START` `TRANSACTION`, `COMMIT`, or `ROLLBACK`.